# CSS Grid Overlay on a background video

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[screenshot of homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfrkS.jpg)I have ran into a bit of trouble which I am struggling to fix. I am trying to learn react and I have built a very basic website. I am currently trying to make my CSS grid containing a title and 3 img buttons to be in the centre of the screen and on top of the video that is playing. So far my screen looks like the image attached. As seen the image, the grid at the bottom of the page needs to be in the center of the video. All functionality works, its just the display I can't seem to get right.

My code for the homepage is:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../styles/Home.css';
import HomeVideo from'../assets/videoForWebsite.mp4'
import imperium from '../assets/ventris.jpg'
import xenos from '../assets/eldar.jpg'
import chaos from '../assets/despoiler.jpg'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Imperium from '../pages/Imperium.jsx';

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="home">
      <div className = "homeVideo">
        <video src={HomeVideo} autoPlay loop muted/>
        <div className='wrapper'>
          <div id='gridTitle'>
            <h1>Warhammer 40k Factions</h1>
          </div>
          <div id='imperiumButton'>
            <Link to="/Imperium">
              <button className="img-size"><img src={imperium}/></button>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div id='chaosButton'>
            <Link to="/chaos">
              <button className="img-size"><img src={chaos}/></button>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div id='xenosButton'>
            <Link to="/xenos">
              <button className="img-size"><img src={xenos}/></button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

My CSS code is here:

```
.home{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;  
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper{
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center; 
}

#gridTitle{
  grid-column-start:1 ;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  text-align: center;
}

#imperiumButton{
  grid-column-start:1 ;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

#chaosButton{
  grid-column-start:2 ;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

#xenosButton{
  grid-column-start:3 ;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.img-size img{
  width: 10vw;
  height: 15vh;
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I have tried multiple attempts of using CSS grids, including adding the video into a grid layout.

Comment: right now you are rendering your `div.wrapper` as a block element just after the `<video>` in the document flow. If you wish it to stay at the center of the screen regardless of other element occupying space and by covering everything below, you should set its position as absolute. You may start trying to add `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); padding: 20px;` to the `.wrapper` css rule and `position: relative` to the `.home` css rule